# In "O Tannenbaum", is "zur Sommerzeit" a tongue-twister for native speakers?

Tags: pronunciation

Whenever I sing "O Tannenbaum", I have to concentrate really hard to pronounce the z-S-z correctly (i.e., "ts"-"Z"-"ts" using English sounds) instead of, e.g., z-Z-z (i.e., zur Zommerzeit). Is this just because I'm not that fluent, or is this a problem (perhaps milder) for native speakers as well?

Comment: This is probably opinion-based? But no, no tongue-twister for me. Didn’t notice anything when my kids were small either.

Comment: To make it short: No.

Comment: A tongue-twister would be *Fischers Fritze fischt frische Fische. Frische Fische fischt Fischers Fritze.*

Comment: Tweaked the question to clarify that I'm talking about the *correct* pronunciation per @Janka's fine answer.

Comment: @Stephie — possibly opinion-based, but it appears all native speakers have the same opinion. :)

Comment: Not even for a non-native speaker like me.

Comment: If you have problems with "Sommerzeit", just sing "UTC + 2". ;)

Comment: @userunknown your funny(?) remark might confuse non-native speakers. The "Sommer(s)zeit" in the song is not the daylight-saving-time, it is the summertime (like in Mungo Jerry's song "In the summertime")

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf: Summertime is the time where the fishing is easy, Janis Joplin is crying, not Mungo Jerry and UTC+2 should be evenly hard to understand, worldwide, it is at least not particularly easy for native Germans.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer the actual question without diving into rules of pronunciation:

No, it is not a problem for a native speaker to say "zur Sommerzeit", and not at all would I count this as a tongue-twister.

PS: As @BestGuess says, the original lyrics say "zur Sommer*s*zeit" - that, however, is still easy to pronounce for a native speaker.

Answer (score 2):

Do you refer to the English pronouciation of *z-S-z*? That's sure a tongue-twister. But *z* isn't an *s-sound* in German. It's a *t-sound*.

- German **z** is pronounced similar to the **ts** in *bits*.

The *s* sounds are slightly different and transcribed differently, too.

- German **s** is pronounced similar to the **z** in *lazy*.
- German **ß** is pronounced similar to the **ce** in *race*.
- German **ss** is pronounced similar to the **ss** in *less*.

German has no sound similar to the English *s* at word start. Such an *s* may only appear after other consonants.

(You may argue there's no difference between the *ce* in *race* and the *ss* in *less*. Yep. The difference between *ß* and *ss* is marginal in German, too. It's mostly a matter of orthography. The Swiss don't use ß at all because of this.)

The *sp*, *st* and *sh* sounds are different, too: the lips form a ring as if you want to suck from a straw, but instead, you blow slightly.

- German **sp** is pronounced similar to **shp** (some dialects pronounce it similar to English *sp*).
- German **st** is pronounced similar to **sht** (some dialects pronounce it similar to English *st*).
- German **sch** is pronounced similar to **shhh**.

Comment: What exactly is the difference in the pronunciation of *ß* and *ss*? The s-sound in race and less is exactly the same. Just the length of the vowel before is different: ß means: The vowel before it is spoken long; ss means: short vowel. But the s-sound itself is exactly the same. The difference is not "marginal". It is non-existent.

Comment: In Austria it's even simpler. There is no voiced s (i.e. no sound like z in lazy). We only use the unvoiced s-sound like in *race* or *less*. But yes, the letter "z" is always pronounced as "ts" in German.

Comment: I found those examples are simpler than such a rule, because English speakers aren't used to a vowel pronounciation that follows any rules.

Comment: The difference between ss and ß is not marginal at all. While the s-sound is the same, they change the way the preceding vowel is pronounced. ss follows a short vowel (as in _Schloss_), while ß follows a long one (as in _Schoß_).

Comment: @adhominem I think you might be confusing cause and effect here. The use of _ss_ or _ß_ doesn't change the preceding vowel; it is just the orthographical representation of vowel length.

Comment: @GrottenOlm I did not mean to attribute cause and effect, I simply wanted to point out that there is a significant difference between ss and ß

Comment: @Janka, actually I was referring to the ts-Z-ts sound combination (using the English sounds here now). I definitely would find the z-S-z to actually be easier, but perhaps that's the difference between a native speaker of English and a native speaker of German.

Answer (score 1):

To add to what has already been said, i believe the traditional text is not 
"zur Sommerzeit", 
but "zur Sommer**s**zeit", 
where the later is in fact a bit of a tonguetwister ('sz' in the middle). Which eventually led to the version quoted by you, where the trailing 's' of Sommer is omited.

[image]

Comment: You're correct about "Sommerszeit" - the original lyrics don't say "Sommerzeit". However, that doesn't make it more of a tongue twister, actually...

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar: Of course it does. That is the exact reason why most people say "Sommerzeit" noaways. Pronouncing and 's' before a 'z' forces you to make a short break to move your lips. If you do not make a break, then the (similar) sounds will merge into each other. Most people have chosen not to make that break.

Comment: @BestGuess, very interesting!

Comment: @BestGuess I respectfully disagree with a ‘break to move your lips’. If anything, your tongue is moving in what is effectively an s-t-s movement. There are many more words like that in German such as *Auszeit, Eiszeit, Esszimmer* and none of those are tongue-twister-y in any sense of the word. Furthermore, this is a morpheme boundary so having a minimalistic break for the tongue is absolutely no problem (compare *Restsatz* which is clearly distinct from hypothetic *\*Res-Zatz*).

Comment: @Jan: so why do you think that "Sommerszeit" became "Sommerzeit" then? Please also note that all your examples have a vocal before the s-z, while "Sommerszeit" has a consonant.

Comment: @BestGuess I want to argue that both options exist independently because both words are valid German, one with *Fugen-s* the other without. There are a lot of cases where both versions are possible and in usage, e.g. *Einkommensteuer* versus *Einkommenssteuer*.

Comment: @Jan: I would argue that Sommerzeit is a valid german word, but mainly used to describe the part of the year, where we set our clocks to daylight savings. While Sommerszeit is a term to describe a season. It is also far more poetic. See https://sz-magazin.sueddeutsche.de/wortewandel-sprachkolumne/mordlust-oder-mordslust-83168

Comment: @BestGuess I agree that only *Sommerzeit* is used for the time shift from March to October, but at the same time point you to [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/O_Tannenbaum) which has sources for *Sommerzeit* in variants of this song far predating any standardised time.

Comment: @Jan: Point taken. Still far more poetic in my book. But i guess you are right.

Comment: If *sz* would turn a word into a tongue twister, this combination would have become extinct or at least rare in German language over the centuries. But it is not rare. I found more than 2600 words with this combination in a list of German words I downloaded some times ago. Examples: *Auszeit Tageszeitung auszeichnen Ortszeit Öffnungszeit Auszubildende Einkaufszentrum faszinieren ausziehen Disziplin Siegeszug Jahreszahl* and 93 words from my list contain *rsz*, for example *Verkehrszeichen, Kursziel, Verszeile, Alterszucker, Frühjahrszeit.* Non of them is a tongue twister to native speakers.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: if you read my answer, then you will notice that i said "a bit of a" tonguetwister. And if you'd try to **sing** all those words, you have listed, you will find out that an un-trained singer will in fact sing Einkauf-zentrum, Siege-zug, Au-zubildende. Simply because it is easier (not impossible) to spell out.

Comment: @BestGuess I think the reason that Sommerszeit turned into Sommerzeit is simply "modernization" of the language.